# array es una palabra reservada en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buen día. array es una palabra reservada en jquery?

```
var indices= [];
    var generarAleatorios = function(array){
        if(indices.length<array.length){
            while(indices.length<array.length){
                var numAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
                //verificar que el numero aleatorio no haya salido
                if(indices.indexOf(numAleatorio)==-1){
                    indices.push(numAleatorio);
                    console.log(indices);
                    return numAleatorio; 
                }       
            }   
        }else{
            alert("no hay mas fotos, ganastes el juego");
        }
    }
```

TENGO ESTE CODIGO Y NO ENTIENDO EXACTAMENTE. GRACIAS POR SU AYUDA

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** ¿qué tratas de hacer con ese código, qué no entiendes del código?. Mira también [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).  Saludos.

Comment: ese `array` es simplemente un parámetro que le pasan a la función

Comment: No es una palabra reservada. Aunque uses `Array` como identificador será legal pero tendrá consecuencias. Si lo usas como variable global sobreescribirás el constructor `Array`. En ES6 no sucede esto con `let` o `const` al tener un scope siempre local.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que no se entiende muy bien tu codigo ni dices lo que quieres conseguir, puede ser que sea esto lo que buscas?:

```
var indices = [];
var generarAleatorios = function(indices) {

    if(indices.length > 0){

    } else{
        alert("no hay mas fotos, ganaste el juego")
    }
}

generarAleatorios();
```

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

A un `array`, lo puedes llamar `array` no hay problema

```
var array = []; //Esto es valido
```

Comment: Las preguntas que no cumplen lo definido en el centro de ayuda [ask] en la mayoría de las ocasiones, no tienen una respuesta que pueda ayudar al usuario a solucionar su problema.